# Recognize words that consist of two equal parts

Tags: string, prolog, dcg

The task is to recognize words like "abab" and reject words like "aacc". I'm supposed to use DCGs for the purpose but the book on Prolog I'm reading only explains how to use them on lists of atoms, not on strings.

```
?- double("abab", []).
true
?- double("xyz", []).
false
```

This is a "homework" question so feel free to just give me a hint if you don't feel comfortable giving me the answer. I don't really know what to Google.

Comment: It is best to use `:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).` in your source files: This means that your double-quoted strings are **lists of atoms**, so you can conveniently reason about the lists `[a,b,a,b]` and `[x,y,z]` in your case by writing `"abab"` and `"xyz"`.

Comment: @mat That's great. Didn't know you could do that.

Comment: I strongly recommend setting this flag, because it makes reasoning about such lists very convenient and also keeps toplevel answers quite readable. It's much better to use characters than codes.

Answer (score 4):

Strings in Prolog are *lists* of character codes. So, if you know how to use DCGs for lists, you already know how to use them for strings as well. I concur with @mat that lists of characters are more readable, therefore I recommend you set the flag as he suggested in his comment.

That being said, you can use a DCG seq//1 to describe arbitrary strings and use that in a DCG double//0 to describe that such a string has to appear twice. I would also recommend the use of phrase/2 or phrase/3 with DCGs instead of using the predicates the DCG-rules are being transformed into (see @mat's comment). You can define a predicate double/1 with phrase/2 like so:

```
double(D) :-            % the list D as described by
   phrase(double,D).    % the actual DCG double//0

seq([]) -->
   [].
seq([H|T]) -->
   [H],
   seq(T).

double -->
   seq(L),
   seq(L).
```

Querying the calling predicate double/1 yields the following results:

```
   ?- double("abab").
yes
   ?- double("xyz").
no
   ?- double("aacc").
no
   ?- double(D).
D = [] ? ;
D = [_A,_A] ? ;
D = [_A,_B,_A,_B] ? ;
D = [_A,_B,_C,_A,_B,_C] ? ;
...
```

If you insist, you can also use your example queries for double/2 with the above code, but I refer you again to @mat's comment why this is not advisable.

Comment: Well the book says that DCGs get desugared in diff list matchers so you use them like you would the diff list predicates, and that means including the extra argument.

Comment: ... it's not "lists of atoms" but "lists of characters" which are "lists of atoms of length one"

Comment: @LukaHorvat: The book does not give you the whole picture: That's only one particular way to implement DCGs in a Prolog system. Nothing prevents the system to use a completely different implementation. In fact, the DCG need not even be compiled at all to Prolog clauses, but can be interpreted dynamically instead. So, there's no guarantee that any extra arguments are even available. **Always** use the `phrase/[2,3]` interface predicates when working with DCGs, exactly as tas does it.

Comment: @LukaHorvat: Of course, silly me. I didn't even consider using DCGs without phrase/[2,3]. See mat's comment why it's preferable this way. Anyway, thanks for the clarification, I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @false: Concerning your 1st comment: If I didn't include `:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes,chars).` in my `.yaprc` I'd get strings as list of character codes: `"ab"=[97,98]`. With that flag set I get `"ab"=[a,b]`. So *by default* strings are lists of character codes. Concerning your 2nd comment: Thanks for the correction, I changed my wording accordingly :-)